# How to create Activiti BPM process remotely

Tags: java, activiti, workflow-activity

i am using activiti-5.21.0. i have another application deployed on apache-tomee-plus-1.6.0. let say: user apply for leave from this application.
Then i want to create activiti process for college staff to approve leave.
what approach should i use? can we create activiti process remotely from another application?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you, can: those are two different process definitions.

You got a few options, depending on what you mean with 'i am using activiti=5.21.0'. Let's assume you're using Activiti as an embedded library (you simply included the jar). The main thing you have to keep in mind is that in this setup, there is no 'activiti server', you have an embedded engine that connects to the same datasource. You could

- use the same database, but have two different applications. In this case, you need to configure the process engine to use the same database. Simply deploy your second process definition to the engine. Also you have to make sure that users from application A don't have access to the process definitions from application B. That's something you will have to add yourself in your own application logic.
- use another database, one per application. This could make your logic easier, but of course you've got now two schema's to 'maintain'.

Answer (score 0):

if you going to have more application to use activiti, you could consider for activiti server. All interaction via rest service and future upgrade will be easy